# Contents of data returned by HKStatisticsQuery

Tags: swift, healthkit

I'm using following code to get burned energy for today:

```
    func getTodaysSummary(for type:HKQuantityType!, unit u:HKUnit!, completion: @escaping (Double) -> Void) {
        let stepsQuantityType = type

        let now = Date()
        let startOfDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: now)
        let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startOfDay, end: now, options: .strictStartDate)

        let query = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: stepsQuantityType!, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: .cumulativeSum) { (_, result, error) in
            var resultCount = 0.0

            guard let result = result else {
                completion(resultCount)
                return
            }

            if let sum = result.sumQuantity() {
                resultCount = sum.doubleValue(for: u)
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(resultCount)
            }
        }

        healthStore.execute(query)
    }

...

self.getTodaysSummary(for: HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .activeEnergyBurned), unit: HKUnit.kilocalorie(), completion: { (energyBurned) in
  print("\(energyBurned)")
})
```

Now I need to understand, what data does it return? In different sources like apple documentation I read this data should contain all activity including walking, swimming etc.

But in my case it returns only the number 680 (I added this value manually via `+` button on Activity Energy screen of Health app)

[image]

It definetly doesn't include steps I've made during the day.
So the question, do I need to calculate those calories separately? 
Also there are iWatch rings that also seem like not returning by HKStatisticsQuery requests. Should I calculate them separately as well to calculate total burned energy?

Comment: "options: .cumulativeSum" I'd say that it's normal that you only have the "final sum", no? Check there https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkstatisticsoptions ?

Comment: .cumulativeSum is ok, that's what I need. the only thing I don't understand, why this value doesn't include energy burned during walking? should I calculate it myself?

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone does not automatically compute Active Energy. The user must have an Apple Watch in order to get Active and Basal Energy samples automatically written to HealthKit.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll bear it in mind. Can you also confirm my suggestion about steps? Does it include in active energy? If it's not, then it's strange, because the energy is spending when human is walking, right? I just can't find any information about this. I know how to convert steps into calories, I just need to be sure I must do it separately from burned energy data provided by HealthKit.

Comment: I would not try to calculate active energy from steps yourself if I were you because an accurate version of that calculation depends on a lot more than just how many steps the user has taken (their height, weight, walking speed, etc.). Why do you need to calculate active energy for users who do not already have that data in HealthKit? Steps recorded on an iPhone are a poor source of data for calorimeters because users do not necessarily carry their phones with them everywhere.

Comment: of course it's pour source, I don't argue. I don't propose to use it as a single source. but it might give more accuracy in addition to other sources like Active energy, didn't it?